# Online Visual Maths Equation Editor which can be implemented in website?

Tags: javascript, html, math, wysiwyg

I am creating a visual mathematics equation editor online, but I am finding difficulty in making it properly.

Before I continue, I wanted to make sure that there are no website-implementable editors I can use (ones which can do fractions, indices, surds, etc.).

So, is there any?

**UPDATE:** I was just looking online and I saw [Math/Graph TinyMCE](http://www.imathas.com/editordemo/demo.html), but that one still requires user knowledge of LaTeX. I want something exactly like that, but where they can actually just edit the fraction hands-on.

Comment: There's [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/).

Comment: I've tried that, but it's only a library (refer to my question - I want an actual editor).

Comment: Refer to your question? The one where you don't mention what you've tried and what does/doesn't meet your standard?

Comment: I find it hard to create a 'fraction' using html, so I've decided to take a look on the web, and couldn'y really find anything handy.

Comment: Welcome to the club. Does Mathematica have a free browser editor? What have you tried that *didn't* work? You seem to have tried something, but yet, you don't give any impression of what those are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is inevitably going to lead you into learning about [MathML](http://www.w3.org/Math/).

There is a TON of information about it online, but I am no expert.

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer: I work on this tool.*

[**Alfred's Equation Editor (AlfredEq)**](http://sharemath.com/AlfredEq-README.html) does exactly what you ask. Combine it with [**MathJax**](http://www.mathjax.org) for rendering.