# How to make a character appear in a div when the character key has been pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to recreate an input box using divs so that I can create fractions, surds etc inside. I want a user to be able to click on the div and press a key and the correct character appear inside the div, but nothing happens when I click on the div and press a key.

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  renderInputBox('#answerSpace');

  $('#input1').on('click', function() {
    inputSelected = !inputSelected
    console.log(inputSelected);
  })

  let inputSelected = false

  $(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if (inputSelected) {
        $('#input1').text(e.which)
    }
})


function renderInputBox(area) {
  $(area).html('<div class="input" id="input1"></div>')
}
```

CSS

```
.input {
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 24px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(153, 153, 153);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 1px;
}

.input:hover {
  border: 1px solid rgb(49, 156, 255);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgb(49, 155, 255);
  cursor: text;
}
```

Comment: [`.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/)

Comment: can you please add your html to the question

Comment: Why don't you make contenteditable=true into that div?

Comment: `$(document).` not `$('document')` and `e.which == '13'` for Entrer Key

Comment: Might want to read the answers to [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](//stackoverflow.com/q/203198), since `input1` is dynamically added to the DOM.

Comment: I've changed the key press method to this:$(document).keypress(function(e) {
        if (inputSelected) {
            $('#input1').text(e.which)
        }
    })

Comment: @SJC did you see my answer? it worked for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I'm using your approach below you will see the issues you are going to have and I do mention the resources below what you are probably looking for.

There is no problem doing what you want to do, writing pressed keys to a `div`, however, you will have to implement every single basic text editor behavior yourself and that is a very big task.

As an example below, I have implemented `backspace` manually, so when it is pressed, the last character is removed.

While that is easy enough, **what if** the user highlights some letters in the middle of the string? In our case we would still only remove the last character but that is not what you would want.

**What if**, the user wants to click the mouse between 2 characters, how are you going to do that? How will you show the blinking caret or when a new key is pressed add the new text where the caret is and not just to the end?

**What if**, the user presses `Ctrl+Home` or `Shift+Home`?

You see how quickly you are going to end up re-writing basic  editor features.

While the below example shows you what you want to do in it's basic essence, including some changes to make selection better, I think what you do want is a pre-build Text Editor for Math Equations.

This SO post has some suggestions for what you are looking for, talking about several Math Editors:
[**online-visual-maths-equation-editor-which-can-be-implemented-in-website**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127456/online-visual-maths-equation-editor-which-can-be-implemented-in-website)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let inputSelected = false

  renderInputBox('#answerSpace');

  $(document).on('click', function(e) {
    inputSelected = $(e.target).is($('#input1'));
  })

  $(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
    //console.log(e.which);
    if (inputSelected) {
      switch (e.which) {
        case 8: // Backspace
          $('#input1').text($('#input1').text().substring(0, $('#input1').text().length - 1));
          break;
        default:
          $('#input1').text($('#input1').text() + e.key);
      }
    }
    /* Append div with character to #input1 */
  })
})

function renderInputBox(area) {
  $(area).html('<div class="input" id="input1"></div>')
}
```

```css
.input {
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 24px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(153, 153, 153);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 1px;
}

.input:hover {
  border: 1px solid rgb(49, 156, 255);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgb(49, 155, 255);
  cursor: text;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='answerSpace'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a very detailed answer. The project I'm building requires a lot of input boxes with 'irregular' answers like square roots and I haven't yet found anything that has the exact functionality I need

Comment: If none of the editors mentioned in the other post have features you need, you could try contacting the devs/publishers of those editors to see if they can add it or know a tool that has those features. Off course, if none do and you must deal with all the input yourself you can either deal with all the input yourself or could see if one of the editors is open source and build on top of it potentially, that way all the basics are already done for you.

Answer (score 0):

I made a slight change to your code, I changed what I said in the comments above and also used another way to bind the event: `.on('keypress', ...)`.

I also made a way to already write the key to the div, take a look.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  renderInputBox('#answerSpace');

  $('#input1').on('click', function() {
    inputSelected = !inputSelected
    console.log(inputSelected);
  })

  var inputSelected = false

  $(document).on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.which == '13' && inputSelected) {
      console.log('test');      
    }else if (inputSelected){
      console.log(e.key);
      var currentText = $(".input").text();
      $(".input").text(currentText + e.key);
    }
  });
});

function renderInputBox(area) {
  $(area).html('<div class="input" id="input1"></div>')
}
```

```css
.input {
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 24px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(153, 153, 153);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 1px;
}

.input:hover {
  border: 1px solid rgb(49, 156, 255);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgb(49, 155, 255);
  cursor: text;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='answerSpace'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. It was the .text() that I was missing.